# Force HTTP://subdomain. and HTTP://domain. to HTTPS (with .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I got a quick question on redirecting to HTTPS.

I want

to 
 to

How can I make this possible? The point is, that I got several Domains linking to one Directory and I only want to use one single SSL Certificate.

Thanks to everyone out there who can help me :-)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching today I finally found a solution. Maybe it is useful for you so I would like to share:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.tld/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

:-)